# disnake | 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable в

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Пишу бота с получением заявок Modal Dialogs, не могу связать кнопку с анкетой.

```py
client.slash_command()
async def buttons(interaction: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction):
    embed = disnake.Embed(title="**Подать заявку**", description=f"Заявка рассматривается в течении 24 часов!\n Не нужно писать Администрации что-бы проверили вашу заявку!\n\n", color=0x0000FF)
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed,
        components=[
            disnake.ui.Button(label="Подать заявку", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.success, custom_id="yes")
        ],)

class RecruitementModal(disnake.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        components = [
            disnake.ui.TextInput(label="Ваша имя", placeholder="Введите ваша имя", custom_id="name"),
            disnake.ui.TextInput(label="Ваша возрост", placeholder="Введите ваша возрост", custom_id="age")
        ]
        super().__init__(title=title, components=components, custom_id='RecruitementModal')

    async def callback(self, interaction: disnake.ModalInteraction) -> None:
        name = interaction.text_values["name"]
        age = interaction.text_values["age"]
        embed = disnake.Embed(title="Заявка", description=f"Заявка успешно отправлина!", color=0x0000FF)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
        channel= interaction.guild.get_channel(993421342621839432)
        embed = disnake.Embed(title="Заявка", description=f"Имя {name} {interaction.author.mention} ({age} лет)", color=0x0000FF)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

@client.listen("on_button_click")
async def help_listener(interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    if interaction.component.custom_id not in ["yes"]:
        return

    if interaction.component.custom_id == "yes":
        await interaction.response.send_modal(RecruitementModal(interaction.values[0]))
```